# Print window of submitted form without redirection on Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have one issue, how open print window of submitted form without redirection. Now, when I submit form, redirects to submitted form results as well.

Controller. If is neccessary I can create blade file for submited form results to sove this issue.

```
 public function printBarcode(BarcodeRequest $request)
    {
        $bar = new DNS1D();

        $user = User::find(Auth::id());
        $barcodes = $request->input('prints');
            for ($i = 0; $i <= count($barcodes) - 1; $i++) {
                echo '<body onload="window.print();">';
                echo '<div style="text-align: center;  height: 100%">';
                echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . $bar->getBarcodePNG($barcodes[$i], 'C128', $user->barcode_width, $user->barcode_height) . '" alt="barcode" style="width: 50%;"/>';
                echo '<br>';
                echo '<br>';
                echo '<p style="text-align: center; margin-top: 5px;">' . $barcodes[$i] . '</p>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</body>';

            }
    }
```

Form

```
  Locations:
                                            @for($i=0; $i<=count($warehouses)-1; $i++)
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="all" id="all" onclick="toggle(this);">Select/remove all<br>
                                                <form method="get" action="{{route('print.barcode')}}">
                                                    @csrf
                                                    <br>
                                            @for($j=0; $j<=count($locations[$i])-1; $j++)
                                               <input type="checkbox" name="prints[]" value="{{ $locations[$i][$j]['node']['name'] }}"> {{ $locations[$i][$j]['node']['name'] }}
                                                <br>
                                                <br>
                                            @endfor
                                                <button type="submit" valu="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="printBarcode({{route('print.barcode')}});">Print Selected</button>
                                            </form>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="all" id="all" onclick="toggle(this);">Select/remove all<br>
                                            @endfor
```

Javascript part which should handle redirection

```
function printBarcode(url){
    window.location.replace('localhost/home');
    $('body').append('<iframe src="url" id="printIFrame" name="printIFrame"></iframe>');
    $('#printIFrame').bind('load',
        function() {
            window.frames['printIFrame'].focus();
            window.frames['printIFrame'].print();
            window.location.href = 'localhost/home';
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: submit the form in ajax and in the success callback open the print modal

Answer (score 0):

Send query via ajax

```js
function printBarcode(url) {
    var form = $("#myFormId");
    var url = form.attr('action'); //get submit url [replace url here if desired]
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         dataType: "html",
         url: url,
         data: form.serialize(), //serializes form input
         success: function(data){
             //Past to DIV
             $("#printArea").html(data);
             $("#printArea").print();
         }
    });
};
```

or use

window.open(url + '?' + queryString );
and open page in new window

...

Comment: Is possible emulate that with fetch?

Comment: By the way, I tried it your approach but no avail.